# WAN and LAN via the same physical port on a Teltonika router but with different firewall rules?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, lan

*(Note: I [asked](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83851/wan-and-lan-via-the-same-physical-port-on-a-teltonika-router-but-with-different) this question on Stack Exchange Network Engineering but it was closed as off-topic (?!) and I was referred to Super User)*

I have a Teltonika RUTX12 router which has a dedicated WAN port and 4 x LAN ports.

Until now I have been using the router's built-in 4G modem as my main WAN interface and therefore have been able to manage firewall rules fairly easily. For example, I have a "Guest WiFi" network which allows clients to connect to the internet (WAN interface, i.e. 4G) but forbids any communication on the LAN interface (ethernet devices).

However I am no longer using the 4G connection and have switched to gigabit fibre instead. The ISP-supplied modem router is a Fritz!Box 7530 AX and it acts as a gateway to the internet.

I have connected the FritzBox to the Teltonika via ethernet into the Teltonika's LAN1 port,  and I have changed the Teltonika's default gateway (and DHCP server) to the ISP-supplied FritzBox. This allows me to access the internet as well as any LAN devices plugged into the FritzBox's LAN ports, as you would expect.

The problem is the Teltonika's Guest WiFi setup no longer works. As far as it is concerned, there is no WAN interface any more, so clients on the Guest Wifi network have no internet access.

How can I resolve this?

If I plug the FritzBox into the Teltonika's WAN port, that might allow internet access on the WAN interface but (presumably) it would prevent me from accessing any LAN devices plugged into the FritzBox.

Is there a way to configure the Teltonika so it can see a separate WAN and a LAN interface from  a single physical connection on its LAN1 port? Or can I use VLANs to achieve what I want?

The Teltonika is very powerful and allows full configuration of its firewall, interfaces, VLANs, etc. so I believe it should be possible but I don't have enough knowledge to know what approach to take.

Here's a diagram of what I'm looking to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0nKm.png

Comment: Why can't you use just the Fritz!Box? It's got a firewall, but no VLANs (except for the Guest network). Unfortunately I don't think that it's supported by any alternate firmware such as DD-WRT or OpenWrt (even if your ISP agreed to it). Otherwise, you could get a new router.

Comment: Instead of the automatic "guest wi-fi", could you manually configure a second SSID – and define it as a separate IP subnet, not bridged?

Comment: My first guess is that the Teltonika implements the guest network on the WAN interface inside any NAT you have applied. that way the firewall ruleset between WAN Out and LAN In sits between the two. if that is the case, with the WAN disabled, there is no where for the clients to go

Comment: @harrymc I am using the FritzBox downstairs but want to use the Teltonika upstairs where the FritzBox signal doesn't reach. Plus the Teltonika's a great piece of hardware so I don't want to waste it.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I hadn't thought of that but perhaps that'd be possible. Not entirely sure how to set that up in the RUTX12 but I can mess around, thanks.

Comment: @FrankThomas  Your guess sounds right to me, although the device doesn't actually have a built-in Guest WiFi mode; I just followed [a guide](https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/How_to_set_up_a_guest_WiFi_network_on_RUTX) on manually setting up a new WiFi network which is limited only to the WAN interface. As you say, because I no longer *have* a WAN interface, it's broken. So my question really is: can I somehow split my single LAN1 connection into a separate "WAN" and a "LAN" connection?

Answer (score 0):

> I just followed a guide on manually setting up a new WiFi network which is limited only to the WAN interface. As you say, because I no longer have a WAN interface, it's broken. So my question really is: can I somehow split my single LAN1 connection into a separate "WAN" and a "LAN" connection?

That's not limited to the WAN interface or connection, that's limited to the WAN *firewall zone.* While OpenWRT's firewall zones make things a little more automatic and convenient based on interface boundaries, in reality the setup has nothing to do with interfaces as such – it's all about writing firewall rules that correctly say "allow/deny from Y to X".

So you don't really *need* "WAN" or "LAN" distinctions here, you can instead have a basic traffic rule that says "deny to 192.168.1.0/24" (the main LAN subnet) followed by "allow everything", and that's your guest Wi-Fi.